# Launch junit/robolectric tests (gradle)

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, junit, robolectric

I have my **unit/Robolectic** tests located in

```
/app/src/test/java
```

This is made to distinguish android instrumentation tests located in /app/src/androidTest/java

How can I only **run these unit tests** which don't need whole project to be built (which is time consuming) **from command line**?

Is there any gradlew/java command?

I want to obtain the same result as if running from Android Studio junit tests from specific dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. I assume you don't have any flavour:

`./gradlew testDebug -Dtest.single=<your test class>`

Comment: I do have both product flavors and build variants. Also I want to test whole dir, not just single class

Comment: So change `testDebug` to something `test<your flavour>Debug`. I know you can also use wildcards in test name definition but I'm not sure about folders. Google for it